# List of Jasmine tests not showing in browser output when running `ng test`

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I inherited an Angular app that was first worked on a couple of years ago. One of the tasks I've been given is to get our testing going - as tests haven't been run over the last year or more. This was originally an Angular 2 app, and has been updated to be around 2.3.1. At the moment we can't do a further update because it would involve substantial refactoring that we need to tackle at a later time.

Here's the issue, when I run `ng test` it does generate some initial tests. However, when the browser window opens, while I see the Karma details, showing `Karma v1.20 - connected` (see pic), I don't see any of the listing of actual files that are failing or passing via Jasmine.

[image]

It's like the Jasmine portion has been disabled. Or hidden from showing here? Not sure. This is what I would expect to see (screenshot from another app's test results):

[image]

FYI, in the command line I see the tests have run (all are passing):

```
04 04 2019 13:14:48.834:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
04 04 2019 13:14:48.836:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
04 04 2019 13:14:48.851:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
04 04 2019 13:15:15.529:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/    
Chrome 73.0.3683 (Mac OS X 10.14.4): Executed 5 of 5 SUCCESS (0.199 secs / 0.188 secs)
```

I have searched through various files, but so far have been unable to find a portion of Jasmine code that's been disabled or commented-out. So how can I go about finding how to re-enable the Jasmine printout as part of my test run? Can I uninstall and reinstall just a testing package? What's recommended in a situation like this?

I'm also wondering if it could be a problem with my `karma.conf.js` file. This is what mine looks like:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

    module.exports = function (config) {
      config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
          require('karma-jasmine'),
          require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
          require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
          require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
          require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        files: [
          { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
        ],
        preprocessors: {
          './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
        },
        mime: {
          'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
        },
        remapIstanbulReporter: {
          reports: {
            html: 'coverage',
            lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
          }
        },
        angularCli: {
          config: './angular-cli.json',
          environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
                  ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
                  : ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false
      });
    };
```

Comment: I hope you have checked the version compatibility of `karma` and `jasmine` in package.json for Angular 4.

Comment: Yes, version compatibility is not the issue.

Comment: Any updates on the issue? I have the same problem and don't know what it may be... Thank you

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293979/4388875

Answer (score 4):

try to add the following lines to the `karma.conf.js`

```js
client: {
    clearContext: false
}
```