# Angular 13: Cannot see Jasmine tests in browser

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a new Angular project, in which every single test completes, but they won't show anything in the karma window. There is no "preview" for my components there. Pretty similar to what is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521855/list-of-jasmine-tests-not-showing-in-browser-output-when-running-ng-test).

[image]

I have added

```
    client: {
      clearContext: false,
```

As well explicitly, but still nothing.

```
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.0.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1300.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      13.0.3
@angular-devkit/core               13.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         13.0.3
@angular/cli                       13.0.3
@angular/flex-layout               12.0.0-beta.35
@angular/material-moment-adapter   13.0.3
@schematics/angular                13.0.3
rxjs                               7.4.0
typescript                         4.4.4
```

log:

```
ng test
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...09 12 2021 18:01:20.002:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
09 12 2021 18:01:20.008:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
09 12 2021 18:01:20.009:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome, ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
09 12 2021 18:01:20.021:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
09 12 2021 18:01:20.033:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
09 12 2021 18:01:24.496:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
09 12 2021 18:01:24.543:INFO [Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket JIpJoqxVAnpzKs4jAAAC with id 42855238
09 12 2021 18:01:24.551:INFO [Chrome 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket nCRRKzG1hzgEZZ3tAAAD with id 21335426
Chrome Headless 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 92 (skipped 91) SUCCESS (0.132 secs / 0.046 secs)
Chrome 94.0.4606.71 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 92 (skipped 91) SUCCESS (0.14 secs / 0.048 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

Comment: Did you try to FAIL the test?

Comment: yes, it doesn't matter, there is still no outputl.

Comment: Also make sure that the your tests actually produces DOM (you are running only a subset now, 1 of 92). Also do not reset the TestBed after the test .

Comment: I can find DOM elements in the tests, even MaterialHarnesses work as intented. I just cannot see them. How can you make sure not to reset the TestBed? I know there is something changed regarding this in Angular 13...

Comment: I dont know that, im stuck in angular 10, but if it is reset by default after each test then this would be the case (I just had the same problem with handsontable tests;))

Comment: thank you, it seemd that the deafult optimization is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Angular 13 they introduced a new optimization feature for tests:

From https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296

> We’ve made some important improvements to TestBed that now does a
> better job of tearing down test modules and environments after each
> test. The DOM is now cleaned after every test and developers can
> expect faster, less memory-intensive, less interdependent, and more
> optimized tests.

To opt out, I needed to insert this code to every TestBed:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [TestComp],
        teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false } // true by default after Angular 13
    });
});
```

Comment: I am wondering now, is it a bad practice to have a visual inspection possibility? Since now by default it is "hidden" i have more boilerplate things to to make it behave like before

Comment: I thnk it's ok to hide it normally, but while you are debugging a single test with `fit` it's useful to see, what gets rendered, without the need to step through the test itself for a quick peek.

Comment: True, espcially if running in eg headless on CI pipeline. I think it should be possible to switch that optimalization on/off globally as locally I want it to be shown but on CI not rly.